# Do you know which series or set this sticker is from?

Tags: set-identification, sticker-identification

[image]

Can you identify the series for this sticker? Or even better, do you know which set it is from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome. This is part [52031pb093 - Wedge 4 x 6 x 2/3 Triple Curved with Gold and Silver Ring Ornament on Dark Green Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52031pb093&name=Wedge%204%20x%206%20x%202/3%20Triple%20Curved%20with%20Gold%20and%20Silver%20Ring%20Ornament%20on%20Dark%20Green%20Pattern%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%2076006&category=%5BWedge,%20Decorated%5D#T=P&C=11) which comes from set [76006 Iron Man: Extremis Sea Port Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76006-1#T=P) from 2013.

[image]